# EAR with EJB and WAR modules fails to deploy WAR dependencies

Tags: eclipse, war, ear

I have an EAR that has many EJB modules and one WAR. The WAR dependencies are not picked up. There are only 3 of the WAR dependencies that are not already included in the EAR. These are ones that break the deployment. The target web logic server starts in Eclipse but the app fails to publish. As a test, when I add the missing WAR dependencies to any of the EJB modules they are picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with certain versions of the m2eclipse plugin from Sonatype.
Some versions of the plugin do not correctly propogate the dependencies for the web project (WAR).
The plugin that works is the one that is installed in version 3.6.2 of eclipse. The one in 3.6.0 doesn't work.
Once I woved to version 3.6.2 of eclipse the problem went away.
Granted the issue may also have been tied to the plugin verions PLUS the version of eclipse.

Here are the maven plugin and eclipse details:

Works:
m2eclipse - 0.12.1.20110112-1712 running in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110218-0911

Doesn't work: 
m2eclipse - 0.12.0.20101115-1102 running in Eclipse Java EE Version: 3.6.0 Build id: I20100608-0911